# Zurb Foundation 5 close an alert box with personal button

Tags: alert, zurb-foundation-5

I'd like to "extend" the alert-box to have for example a confirm box or a prompt box but I also want to keep using the callback function close to store informations in a database for example.

the structure of my alert-box could be something like this :

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box success">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    <h4>This is a <span class="bold">title</span></h4>
    <p>This is an error alert a bit more complex.</p>
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="button alert-box-close">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="button alert">Cancel</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

The problem I have is how the `.alert-box-close` class works like the `.close` class ?

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to file(if you load each module separately)

foundation.alert.js

line 23

```
$(this.scope).off('.alert').on('click.fndtn.alert', '[' + this.attr_name() + '] a.close', function (e) {
```

you make it like that

```
$(this.scope).off('.alert').on('click.fndtn.alert', '[' + this.attr_name() + '] a.close, .any-class-name', function (e) {
```

Comment: Thanx but I rewrote the project with twitter bootstrap :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery to hide the alert-box

```
   <div data-alert class="alert-box">
   <!-- Your content goes here -->
   <a href="#" id="closebutton" class="alert button">close</a>
   </div>
```

and the jquery is,

```
   $( "#closebutton" ).click(function() {
      $(this).parent().hide();
   });
```

Comment: Hi and thanx for your answer. That's the first thing I've tried but with this method the callback function won't work anymore :(

Comment: I don't know what you exactly want!
just write more in the question
if you want to show the alert box once again just ad an event listener and id to  data-alert div and show the div when event fires using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This way work for me.

```
$(".alert-box .close").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

And before showing again, can put something like this:

```
$(".alert-box")
                    .removeClass("alert-close")
                    .removeClass("hide")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .show();
```